# How to create global helper functions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create some global helper functions.
I understood that i must place them in a .cshtml file in App_Code.
I created this file:

```
@helper CreatePostForm(string action, string controller, string id, params string[] hiddens)
{       
    using (BeginForm(action, controller, System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { id = id }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        foreach(string hidden in hiddens)
        {
            @Html.Hidden(hidden)   
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `BeginForm` and `AntiForgeryToken` methods are nor recognized.
How to make it right?

PS: i am using .net 4.5, asp.net mvc 4

Comment: For those who would need global helper functions in ASP.NET Core I presented a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331157/replacement-for-helper-in-asp-net-core#answer-64128608

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to pass in the `HtmlHelper` object as a parameter into your helper:

```
@helper CreatePostForm(HtmlHelper html, 
                       string action, string controller, string id, 
                       params string[] hiddens)
{       
    using (html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new { id = id }))
    {
        @html.AntiForgeryToken()
        foreach(string hidden in hiddens)
        {
            @html.Hidden(hidden)   
        }
    }
}
```

You should also add the required `@using` statements to your helper file to make the extension methods like `BeginForm` work:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Web.Mvc
```

And then you need to call your helper method something like this:

```
@MyHelpers.CreatePostForm(Html, "SomeAtion", "SomeContoller" , "SomeId")
```

Comment: I still can't access those methods on html parameter. Secondly, i can use Html in that cshtml. The problem is with those extension methods( BeginForm, AntiForgeryToken).

Comment: These are all extension methods have you added the required usings at the top of your helper file? `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: I don't really like passing `Html` as an input. But adding `this` to try and make an extension didn't work on my helper. Is there any other way? (Other than a real extension class, which is harder to build.)

Comment: @ashes999 There is no other way. If you want to a global helper method and use `Html` then you need to pass in a `HtmlHelper`. Or you need to create a proper extension class and create a regular `HtmlHelper` extension.

Comment: You don't have to pass anything to global helper functions. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495748/1185136).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass the `HtmlHelper` object as a parameter. Just put this in your .cshtml file residing in App_Code:

```
@functions {
    private new static HtmlHelper<dynamic> Html => ((WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;
}
```

Other useful members are:

```
private static UrlHelper Url => ((WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Url;
```

```
private static ViewContext ViewContext => ((WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).ViewContext;
```