# Replacement for @helper in ASP.NET Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So far, i don't think `ViewComponent` solves that neither does `TagHelper`. Is there any replacement to this? Something that takes parameters and returns a `HtmlString`?

I don't see anything harmful with:

```
@helper foo(string something) {
     <div>Say @something</div>
}

var emailbody = classfilenameinAppCodefolder.foo("hello"); //store result in a variable for further processes
```

For now i believe its a temporary delete before RC. https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/281 and https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1130 Well! it better be. I hope someone is working on it. Without `@helper`, building large `HtmlString` or 'template' would be a serious pain.

Note: Partial View doesn't seem to do the trick. I think it only renders views not return view to variable.

Secondly, what happened to the App_Code folder?

Comment: What's wrong with `ViewComponent`? It can return an `HtmlString` too if that's what your issue is.

Comment: ViewComponent is similar to partialView but more powerful. The question is, can i store the html result of this Component in a variable for further manipulation within my logic. I'm not interested in rendering into a section of a view from a view. I'm interested in generating a view on the fly and storing it in a variable in a more simplistic way like @helper. ViewComponent for all i can see looks too elaborate.

Comment: Yes, I also agree that ViewComponent seems like too much? Say I just want a tiny snippet of HTML? If I use a view component, that HTML has to exist in a C# file, which surely isn't right? I can return a view from the component that contains the HTML snippet but then I've got two files for just a tiny snippet of HTML.

Comment: @IfeanyiChukwu, which solution did you end up going with here? Neither a ViewComponent or TagHelper is a sufficient replacement here.

Comment: The helper functions were wonderful because they returned an HtmlString, which could either be rendered immediately or passed around for later rendering.  The removal of the helper functions has broken my grid system in a big project. I thought upgrading would take me forward, but this is a big setback.

Answer (score 34):

According to the following Github issue, it looks like @helper is coming back and will be included in asp .net core 3.0.0 preview 4.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5110

**UPDATE**

Starting in asp .net core 3, you can now define a local function within a Razor code block.

```
@{
    void RenderName(string name)
    {
        <p>Name: <strong>@name</strong></p>
    }

    RenderName("Mahatma Gandhi");
    RenderName("Martin Luther King, Jr.");
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#razor-code-blocks

Alternatively you can use the @functions directive like this:

```
@{
    RenderName("Mahatma Gandhi");
    RenderName("Martin Luther King, Jr.");
}

@functions {
    private void RenderName(string name)
    {
        <p>Name: <strong>@name</strong></p>
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#functions

Comment: Miracle didn't happen. Still not working in .net core 3 release

Comment: @SergeiShvets I've updated my answer here to include what I think is an appropriate alternative to helper

Comment: @GaryBrunton Have you tried what you posted? These not working in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor CSHTML. If I try to enter html in local function I get the error that html cant be accepted. The function has the same problem.

Comment: @Tomas I'm in the process of updating to asp net core 3.1 so no I haven't tried it yet but the documentation is very clear here. If it's not working for you I'd suggests possibly creating a github issue in the appropriate repository. I'm hopeful that I'll be able to use this new feature myself within the next month or so.

Comment: I just tried both local functions and the @functions directive and they both worked for me on 3.0. Resharper is showing errors but the code works when ran. I'll try and get it going for 3.1 soon and try it.

Comment: I'm now using this in an asp.net core 3.1 app and it works as documented.

Answer (score 17):

```
@{
    Func<String, IHtmlContent> foo = @<div>Say @item</div>;
}
```

Comment: Here's some context to this idea: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/715#issuecomment-198456302

Comment: How to use it without any parameters? (e.g. Func<IHtmlContent> ... not work)

Comment: With latest .net core this renders nothing sadly

Comment: @jjxtra of course this renders nothing! This is a function definition. You need to call this function and write result to page for render it's content

Comment: Did that, ran into issues and went with a different solution. Probably I had something messed up on my end.

Comment: Where do I put this so it's visible from all my views?

Answer (score 11):

For .NET Core 3, you can use local functions:

```
@{
    void RenderName(string name)
    {
        <p>Name: <strong>@name</strong></p>
    }

    RenderName("Mahatma Gandhi");
    RenderName("Martin Luther King, Jr.");
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#razor-code-blocks

Answer (score 10):

As [@scott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331157/replacement-for-helper-in-asp-net-core#answer-59506672) pointed out in his answer, [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#razor-code-blocks) are finally available as of .NET Core 3. In prior versions one can resort to [templated Razor delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-1.0#templated-razor-delegates).

But none of the answers addresses the question "what happened to the App_Code folder?" The aforementioned features are local solutions, that is, helper functions defined in these ways cannot be shared between multiple views. But global helper functions could often be more convenient than the solutions MS provide out-of-the-box for view-related code re-use. (Tag helpers, partial views, view components all have their cons.) This was thoroughly discussed in [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/715) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5110) GitHub issue. According to these discourses, unfortunately, there's not much understanding from MS's side, so not much hope is left that this feature will be added any time soon, if ever.

However, after digging into the framework sources, I think, I could come up with a viable solution to the problem.

The core idea is that we can utilize the Razor view engine to look up an arbitrary view for us: e.g. a partial view which defines some local functions we want to use globally. Once we manage to get hold of a reference to this view, nothing prevents us from calling its public methods.

The `GlobalRazorHelpersFactory` class below encapsulates this idea:

```
public interface IGlobalRazorHelpersFactory
{
    dynamic Create(string helpersViewPath, ViewContext viewContext);
    THelpers Create<THelpers>(ViewContext viewContext) where THelpers : class;
}

public class GlobalRazorHelpersOptions
{
    public Dictionary<Type, string> HelpersTypeViewPathMappings { get; } = new Dictionary<Type, string>();
}

public sealed class GlobalRazorHelpersFactory : IGlobalRazorHelpersFactory
{
    private readonly ICompositeViewEngine _viewEngine;
    private readonly IRazorPageActivator _razorPageActivator;

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string> _helpersTypeViewPathMappings;

    public GlobalRazorHelpersFactory(ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine, IRazorPageActivator razorPageActivator, IOptions<GlobalRazorHelpersOptions>? options)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewEngine));
        _razorPageActivator = razorPageActivator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(razorPageActivator));

        var optionsValue = options?.Value;
        _helpersTypeViewPathMappings = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string>(optionsValue?.HelpersTypeViewPathMappings ?? Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<Type, string>>());
    }

    public IRazorPage CreateRazorPage(string helpersViewPath, ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.GetView(viewContext.ExecutingFilePath, helpersViewPath, isMainPage: false);

        var originalLocations = viewEngineResult.SearchedLocations;

        if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
            viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(viewContext, helpersViewPath, isMainPage: false);

        if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
        {
            var locations = string.Empty;

            if (originalLocations.Any())
                locations = Environment.NewLine + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, originalLocations);

            if (viewEngineResult.SearchedLocations.Any())
                locations += Environment.NewLine + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, viewEngineResult.SearchedLocations);

            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The Razor helpers view '{helpersViewPath}' was not found. The following locations were searched:{locations}");
        }

        var razorPage = ((RazorView)viewEngineResult.View).RazorPage;

        razorPage.ViewContext = viewContext;

        // we need to save and restore the original view data dictionary as it is changed by IRazorPageActivator.Activate
        // https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.6/src/Mvc/Mvc.Razor/src/RazorPagePropertyActivator.cs#L59
        var originalViewData = viewContext.ViewData;
        try { _razorPageActivator.Activate(razorPage, viewContext); }
        finally { viewContext.ViewData = originalViewData; }

        return razorPage;
    }

    public dynamic Create(string helpersViewPath, ViewContext viewContext) => CreateRazorPage(helpersViewPath, viewContext);

    public THelpers Create<THelpers>(ViewContext viewContext) where THelpers : class
    {
        var helpersViewPath = _helpersTypeViewPathMappings.GetOrAdd(typeof(THelpers), type => "_" + (type.Name.StartsWith("I", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? type.Name.Substring(1) : type.Name));

        return (THelpers)CreateRazorPage(helpersViewPath, viewContext);
    }
}
```

After introducing the singleton `IGlobalRazorHelpersFactory` service to DI, we could inject it in views and call the `Create` method to acquire an instance of the view which contains our helper functions.

By using the `@implements` directive in the helper view, we can even get type-safe access:

```
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage
@implements IMyGlobalHelpers

@functions {
    public void MyAwesomeGlobalFunction(string someParam)
    {
        <div>@someParam</div>
    }
}
```

(One can define the interface type to view path mappings explicitly by configuring the `GlobalRazorHelpersOptions` in the ordinary way - by `services.Configure<GlobalRazorHelpersOptions>(o => ...)` - but usually we can simply rely on the naming convention of the implementation: in the case of the `IMyGlobalHelpers` interface, it will look for a view named `_MyGlobalHelpers.cshtml` at the regular locations. Best to put it in `/Views/Shared`.)

Nice so far but we can do even better! It'd be much more convenient if we could inject the helper instance directly in the consumer view. We can easily achieve this using the ideas behind `IOptions<T>`/`HtmlLocalizer<T>`/`ViewLocalizer`:

```
public interface IGlobalRazorHelpers<out THelpers> : IViewContextAware
    where THelpers : class
{
    THelpers Instance { get; }
}

public sealed class GlobalRazorHelpers<THelpers> : IGlobalRazorHelpers<THelpers>
    where THelpers : class
{
    private readonly IGlobalRazorHelpersFactory _razorHelpersFactory;

    public GlobalRazorHelpers(IGlobalRazorHelpersFactory razorHelpersFactory)
    {
        _razorHelpersFactory = razorHelpersFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(razorHelpersFactory));
    }

    private THelpers? _instance;
    public THelpers Instance => _instance ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("The service was not contextualized.");

    public void Contextualize(ViewContext viewContext) => _instance = _razorHelpersFactory.Create<THelpers>(viewContext);
}
```

Now we have to register our services in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IGlobalRazorHelpersFactory, GlobalRazorHelpersFactory>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IGlobalRazorHelpers<>), typeof(GlobalRazorHelpers<>));
```

Finally, we're ready for consuming our global Razor functions in our views:

```
@inject IGlobalRazorHelpers<IMyGlobalHelpers> MyGlobalHelpers;

@{ MyGlobalHelpers.Instance.MyAwesomeGlobalFunction("Here we go!"); }
```

This is a bit more complicated than the original App_Code + static methods feature but I think this is the closest we can get. According to my tests, the solution also works nicely with runtime compilation enabled. I haven't had the time so far to do benchmarks but, in theory, it should generally be faster than using partial views as the shared view is looked up only once per consumer view and after that it's just plain method calls. I'm not sure about tag helpers though. It'd be interesting to do some benchmarks comparing them. But I leave that up to the adopter.

(Tested on .NET Core 3.1.)

**Update**

You can find a working demo of this concept in my ASP.NET boilerplate project:

- [Infrastructure](https://github.com/adams85/aspnetskeleton2/tree/9014cf87fe3b5450053f23dd0d0da06c5b515ac0/src/UI.AspNetCore/Infrastructure/ViewFeatures) (relevant files are only those whose name contains *GlobalRazorHelpers*)
- [Registration](https://github.com/adams85/aspnetskeleton2/blob/9014cf87fe3b5450053f23dd0d0da06c5b515ac0/src/UI.AspNetCore/Startup.UI.cs#L156-L161)
- [Helper interface sample](https://github.com/adams85/aspnetskeleton2/blob/9014cf87fe3b5450053f23dd0d0da06c5b515ac0/src/UI.AspNetCore/Areas/Dashboard/Pages/Shared/Helpers/IDataTableHelpers.cs)
- [Helper implementation sample](https://github.com/adams85/aspnetskeleton2/blob/9014cf87fe3b5450053f23dd0d0da06c5b515ac0/src/UI.AspNetCore/Areas/Dashboard/Pages/Shared/Helpers/_DataTableHelpers.cshtml)
- [Usage sample](https://github.com/adams85/aspnetskeleton2/blob/9014cf87fe3b5450053f23dd0d0da06c5b515ac0/src/UI.AspNetCore/Areas/Dashboard/Pages/Settings/Partials/_SettingsTable.cshtml#L13)

Comment: What you have done here is the holy grail of the @helper resurrection! I love it!! Thank you!!

For others that want to implement this solution, there is a part of the procedure that I had some issues figuring it out. You need to create (probably in the same file as the other classes) an interface like this:     
public interface IMyGlobalHelpers { public void MyAwesomeGlobalFunction(string someParam) { } }, and for any new method in _MyGlobalHelpers.cshtml you need to add it with the same signature to the interface aswell, this is the only extra you need to do compared with the old helper.

Comment: @Desmond I'm glad you like it! I updated my answer with links to a complete sample. I hope this will help you to grasp the idea more easily. (As a side note, theoretically you can get along without interfaces by simply injecting `IGlobalRazorHelpersFactory` and using the `Create` overload which returns `dynamic`. However, you lose strong typing this way, so I don't recommend it in professional projects.)

Comment: Works like charm, thanks. Do recent framework versions still lack a built-in solution?

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to expand on @Alexaku's answer and show how I've implemented a helper like function. It's only useful on one specific page but it allows you to execute a piece of razor code multiple times with input parameters. The syntax is not great but I've found it very useful in the absence of razor's @helper function. First declare some kind of Dto that will contain the input parameters into the function.

```
@functions {
   private class Dto
   {
      public string Data { get;set; }
   }
}
```

Then declare the razor function. Note that the displayItem value can be multi-line and also note that you access the Dto variable using the @item.

```
@{
   Func<Dto, IHtmlContent> displayItem = @<span>@item.Data</span>;
}
```

Then when you want to use the razor template you can call it like the following from anywhere in the page.

```
<div>
   @displayItem(new Dto {Data = "testingData1" });
</div>
<div>
   @displayItem(new Dto {Data = "testingData2" });
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to define a function what accepts 2+ parameters?

Comment: @Artiom You can add multiple parameters to the Dto class and use them in the function.

Answer (score 4):

The `@helper` directive [was removed](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/pull/323) since it was incomplete and its current design did not fit in the new 'ASP.NET 5 way'. One of the reasons is that helpers should be declared in the `App_Code` folder while ASP.NET 5 [has no concept of special folders](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1130#issuecomment-66932132). Therefore the team decided to temporarily remove the feature.

There are plans to bring it back in the future though. See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/471#issuecomment-127132048) and [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/472).

Comment: Well....it is very clear i wont be having anything to do with ASP.NET 5 any time soon. I rather stick to 4 or migrate to node.js if necessary. I cant guarantee its direction so far. It looks like a fresh learning curve for me. I aint got that time guys....Too much to learn this days

Comment: Helpers can be also declared inline in the razor file. That would be very helpful, even without global helpers in `App_Code`.

Comment: As of 2018 this is still a problem and a feature gap. Go figure.

Comment: It is the future.. And you should use `ViewComponent` to achieve this now. It is actually a lot more usefull, eg you can use Dependancy Injection

Comment: There are plans to bring an equivalent of @helper back in 3.0: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5110

Comment: Have they made up their minds?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily replace that "feature" with a ViewComponent (and a TagHelper if you want). ASP.NET Core is much more friendly to web designers, and the ViewComponents allow you to write HTML without any (weird to most) razor code.

For example:

1. Create a `SayComponent : ViewComponent` class:

   ```
   public class SayComponent : ViewComponent
   {
       public void Render(string message)
       {
           return View(message);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a View file under `Views/Shared/Say/Default.cshtml` with just

   ```
   @model string

   <div>Message: @Model.</div>
   ```
3. And call it:

   ```
   @await Component.RenderAsync("Say", "some message")
   ```

For a better experience, add this to your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file:

```
@addTagHelper *, YourSolutionName
```

And then you can use it as a tag helper:

```
<vc:say message="some message"></vc:say>
```

Comment: Umm.. void returning a View?

Comment: I don't get how this is a valid alternative to a helper. I have a helper in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project that is 3 lines of simple HTML. If I replace it with a ViewComponent I have to create two files (code-behind and view) just for a tiny snippet of HTML? What should I be using for this scenario?

Comment: If I considered a tag helper instead, then the HTML would have to exist inside a string in a C# file, meaning I lose intellisense and readability. That's surely wrong?

Answer (score -1):

How about using partials to recreate reusable tags?

`MyProject/Views/Shared/_foo.cshtml`

```
@model string

<div>@Model</div>
```

`MyProject/Views/Courses/Index.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<div>
   <partial name="_foo" model="foo" />
   <partial name="_foo" model="bar" />
   <partial name="_foo" model="baz" />
</div>
```

Comment: It's not the same thing