# How to reuse HTML snippets in asp.net core razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I try to reuse HTML snippets in my razor page (view component) but somehow it never call or hit the break in the html section.

I'm using Asp.net core 2.2

```
        @{
        Func<CategorySimpleModel, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent> DisplayManufacturerPicture=
            @<div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="row">
                    @foreach (var m in item.Manufacturers)
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            blah blah
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>;
        }

   @foreach (var root in Model.Categories)
            { 
               DisplayManufacturerPicture (root);
            }
```

Comment: You might want to check out [Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-components/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: that's .net core 3.0 preview, I'm using 2.2 only.

Comment: "but somehow it never call or hit the break in the html section" What exactly do you mean? Did you place a breakpoint inside the Func and it's not getting hit?

Comment: yes it never hits and I've even tried with a simple string func<string, IHtmlContent>. strangely it never shows anything though for loop does hit DisplayManufacturerPicture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somehow it only works with @ though the method call is inside the server side syntax

```
 @if (root.Manufacturers.Count > 0)
{
   @DisplayManufacturerPicture(root);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not (yet) possible. You should take a look at [partial views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2) instead:

```
@foreach (var root in Model.Categories)
{
    <partial name="_DisplayManufacturerPicture" model="root" />
}
```

And then inside `_DisplayManufacturerPicture.cshtml`:

```
@model CategorySimpleModel

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var m in item.Manufacturers)
        {
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                blah blah
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes I do use a lot of partial view, what I'm trying to do is the way to replace legacy @helper from old asp.net. You may see https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-reuse-html-snippets-in-cshtml-view/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331157/replacement-for-helper-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Partial views are *not* legacy and also note that I am not using the HtmlHelper either. And none of this is “old ASP.NET”.