# How to reused html code in multple views?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

My asp.net core 2.0 mvc project has multiple views, they all need to the almost same HTML structure, for instance

```
<div id="ajaxContentPlaceHolder1">
</div>
```

Requirements:

1. I have to reuse the proceeding piece of code accross multiple views. These views use _Layout.cshtml.
2. The piece of code itself, is best to be written in a place with syntax highlight.
3. It's best to generate the ID randomly or incrementally, and there is a way to retrieve the id in another place of the view, in case one view needs the code more than once.

I'm new to asp.net (core) mvc. My first thought is `@help` directive. It turns out asp.net core doesn't support it.

I think I can define tag helper in C#, but C# code file doesn't have HTML syntax highlight.

What is the best way to achieve the requirements?

Comment: I think partial views might be a good fit for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Here is another idea about how to use @ functions instead of @ helper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331157/replacement-for-helper-in-asp-net-core