# Repeating HTML section in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a block of HTML I need to render in multiple places on a page, and I'm looking for a way to only define that HTML once. I can't rely simply on a loop because the HTML appears in different areas.

I know I can use a partial view. But since the block of HTML will only be displayed one one page, I'd prefer to define it there.

I know I can create a `@functions` block to create a function to render the markup, but this is geared towards code and not markup. I'd like something more like `@helper` functions in MVC, but those don't appear to be available in Razor Pages.

Can anyone offer other suggestions for defining a block of HTML in one place so it can be shown anywhere on the page?

Comment: Try using LayoutPages and define your HTML in it. LayoutPages can be shown in 'n' number of pages provided the webpage is linked with it.

Comment: @RohanRao: A layout page includes Razor Pages, not the other way around. Seems like a partial view makes more sense than a layout page, and I've already explained why I don't think that's ideal for me. Unless you're referring to a different type of layout page.

Comment: I have used partial Html for exact same scenarios before, But if you really don't want to use partial html you could define a prefab of your code and use Javascript to insert it where ever you need it without relying on C# at all.

Comment: @SoorenaAban: A partial view would work fine. But since it's only used on one page, I'd prefer to keep everything together. I'd prefer to write markup like you could with `@helper` functions in MVC. It wouldn't be worth it for me (for ease of use, readability, maintainability, and performance) to use JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacement for @helper in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331157/replacement-for-helper-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @MikeBrind: That question provides information about what happened to `@helper` functions, but doesn't do much in the way of how to replace it. It does suggest that a replacement might be on the way.

Comment: One of the answers provides a solution for .NET Core 2.x, and a comment points to the "helper" replacement introduced in .NET Core 3. I've summarised both in a reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with .NET Core 3, you can include HTML tags in methods declared in an `@functions` block e.g.

```
@functions{
    void Greeter()
    {
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
    }
}
```

Then in the content part of the page:

```
@{ Greeter(); }
```

The kind of helper can also take parameters:

```
void Greeter(string greeting)
{
    <div>@greeting World</div>
}

@{ Greeter("Hello"); }
```

If you are working with ASP.NET Core 2.x, your "helper" method is a `Func<someType, IHtmlString>`. In the following example, the *someType* is a `string`:

```
Func<string, IHtmlContent> Greeter = @<h1>Hello @item</h1>;
```

Then in the content part of the page:

```
@Greeter("World");
```

*someType* can be a complex type:

```
Func<Contact, IHtmlContent> Greeter = @<h1>Hello @item.FirstName</h1>;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. People who don't understand the question or just don't know the answer voted to close the question. And then someone comes along and provided the exact answer. (Per the question tags, I am using ASP.NET Core.) Thanks.

Comment: I got this working; however, I'm getting a bunch of warnings. If you'd be so kind, perhaps you could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792542/errors-and-warnings-using-functions-block-in-razor-pages).

Answer (score -1):

Template tag can help:

```html
<template id="block-template">
    <div>
        <p>template contents...</p>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="target1"></div>

<script>
    var tmplt = $("#block-template").html();
    $("#target1").append(tmplt);
</script>
```

the `template` tag is available in HTML5, you can also use script template :

```html
<script id="block-template" type="text/template">
    <div>
        <p>template contents...</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

there is a lot of plugins to use if you need to bind data to the template :

http://handlebarsjs.com/

https://github.com/jcgregorio/stamp/

https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template