# Cannot use markup in local functions in .cshtml in .NET Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to migrate a project from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.1.

.NET Core does not support @helper functions, locally or from App_Code. After looking online, one of the alternatives I've found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331157/replacement-for-helper-in-asp-net-core) is to use [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#razor-code-blocks).

```
// local function
@{
    void RenderName(string name)
    {
        <p>Name: <strong>@name</strong></p>
    }

    RenderName("Mahatma Gandhi");
    RenderName("Martin Luther King, Jr.");
}

// @function
@{
    RenderName("Mahatma Gandhi");
    RenderName("Martin Luther King, Jr.");
}

@functions {
    private void RenderName(string name)
    {
        <p>Name: <strong>@name</strong></p>
    }
}
```

However, neither of these alternatives compile when I copy paste them into the .cshtml file. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.4.2). I get the compiler error around the markup, "statement expected".

[image: syntax error]

I wouldn't expect this code to work in .NET Framework, but I'm finding it confusing because I'm copy/pasting from the official Microsoft documentation for .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: The Code you posted works when i pasted it into my .cshtml file.

Comment: @MOSCODE Do you get intellisense underlining in your .cshtml file?

I've just tried running my code, and it actually runs ok (as in it generates the correct html markup), but the intellisense highlights it as an error.

I've edited my original post to attach a picture to make it clearer.

Comment: Confirming this behavior in .net 5 as well. Yes it compiles, yes it runs, but intelisense just goes crazy wrong