# Razor Helper Function - Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' - .NET 5

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I'm running my ASP.NET 5 MVC project and it has a razor view with a helper function. But when I load the page, I'm getting a http 500 error since the razor page is not compiling.

The error on the marked line is

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

I tried to put the foreach loop inside the codeblock as well to make it appear like a local function. But it also shows same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55425899/491907

Comment: The link 'Razor void function' didn't helped me as it returns nothing. I want a function which returns HTML and use it inside the foreach loop

Comment: The second link works when I copy paste it on my page. But when I ca;ll the function inside the foreach loop, The same error happens. By the way I'm using .NET 5 and helper functions are depreciated with local functions

Comment: Then change the return type of your function from void. Void cannot return anything. Your function currently prints something (not returns) so to use it you need to do `@{ RenderGrantType(..); }` note the curly braces

Comment: Yes, That makes it working. Thanks @pinkfloydx33

Comment: That answer came from the first link btw. So obviously it had the answer.

Comment: Yes but it's confusing since razor functions exists in 2 forms (type returns and html printers). I'm closing the question