# Is there a way to provide the body of a partial as inner HTML?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

Let's say this is my partial:

```
@model SomeData

<div>
    <div>@Model.Title</div>
    <div>BODY(@Model)</div>
</div>
```

The thing I am looking for is that magic **BODY** "thing", so I can use the partial like this:

```
<partial name="_MyPartial" model="someData">
    @BODY {
        <h1>@Model.Welcome</h1>
        <p>@Model.Text</p>
    }
</partial>
```

Is something similar available already?

*********** UPDATES ****************

I think my question can come down to whether it is possible to do this:

Let's say I define my Model class like this:

```
public class SomeData 
{
    public HtmlString Body { get; set; }
}
```

Then in a view:

```
@{
    var someData = new SomeData
    {
        Body = Html(
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>World</p>
        ),
    };
}
```

Is there some Html helper to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331157/replacement-for-helper-in-asp-net-core

Comment: What will be done with `someData`?

Comment: It is just a Model instance containing some HTML string, and that will be passed to a partial so it can render it. I am trying to find out if it is possible to assign some HTML (not inside a string) to a variable, using some helper that will take care of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is like a Taghelper. You can try the follwoing code.
SomeData.cs

```
    public class SomeData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Welcome { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

MyPartialTagHelper.cs

```
    public class MyPartialTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public SomeData data { get; set; }
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {

            output.TagName = "div";
            output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
            StringBuilder stringb = new StringBuilder();

            stringb.Append("<h1>" + data.Welcome + "</h1>");
            stringb.Append("<p>" + data.Text + "</p>");

            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(stringb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            SomeData Data = new SomeData() { Title = "title" };
            return View(Data);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model SomeData
@addTagHelper *,WebApplication4
@{
    var someData= new SomeData() { Welcome="hello",Text="world"};
}

<div>
    <div>@Model.Title</div>
    <my-partial data=someData/>
</div>
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no, it is not what I want. You are hard coding the body of your partialTag. I am instead looking for a way to pass the body of the partial to a property in partial or tag helper, so the client code can look like this: `<my-partial><h1>hello</h1></my-partial>`. If you know ReactJS, it is something like the `Children` Component's Prop. It is easty to assign a string containing html code to a prop, I was just wondering if it is possible to assign plain HTML/Razor to a property or variable. But it was just for convenience, I can work without it.

Comment: Even something like this:. `var Body = MagicHelper(<h1>Hello @Name</h1>);`